# Gnome 3.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 lts

Tags: gnome, gui

How to I get Gnome 3.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 lts because I want to try it and I don't want to upgrade to a non-lts version of ubuntu.  Without I back porting it?