# Installing Gnome 3.8 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Gnome 3.8 is released and I wanted to have it on my system running Ubuntu 12.04. I came across this:
[Gnome 3.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276646/gnome-3-8-on-ubuntu-12-04-2-lts)

In the answers, it is mentioned that Gnome 3.8 is not available in 12.04 in a straight forward way.

Can someone please explain why?

As far as my understanding,the version 3.8 will be available through software centre only when Canonical provides it through their updates.

1. I have installed Gnome 3 through the PPA provided by the Gnome 3 team. So shouldn’t it be available as soon as a newer version is released in the PPA? Or, does it still depend on the OS version also?
2. The solution mentioned here adds three PPAs to the software source.

   http://www.ubuntukiller.com/2013/03/how-to-installupgrade-gnome-38-in.html

The first PPA(Gnome 3 team) is the one I already have. What are the other two PPAs supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would just run the first PPA and see how Gnome 3.8 works. If there are features missing that you want to have, then add the 2nd PPA.  The testing PPA is like a 'beta' version and the staging PPA is 'alpha' - guaranteed unstable, and yes you risk a possible system 'melt-down' that can only be recovered by having extreme knowledge of the linux / unix command line (or even a possible reinstall). Also please see these
2-articles on restoring your system:
[ubuntu sytem restore-1](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/system-restore-and-ubuntu)and [system restore article-2](http://beginlinux.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/back-in-time-system-restore-on-ubuntu/)

As far as your query, I basically copied and pasted from the link you provided and bolded the answers. Hope this helps!  Personally, I am very happy to see Gnome 3.8 and am looking forward to the release of the pure Gnome (stable version) that is now a recognized distro in the Ubuntu family!  please see this article: [Ubuntu GNOME Remix Joins the Ubuntu Family](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/its-official-ubuntu-gnome-remix-joins-the-ubuntu-family)

Then you need to add the Ricotz testing repository that **contains cutting edge git versions for the shell, gtk, glib, clutter and many Gnome applications and utilities.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**If you want to get some more latest Gnome components and risk the stability of the system even further,** then you can use the Ricotz staging repository that can be correctly used only if you added the previous two.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After upgrading, you will have the latest available Gnome Shell version with many applications and utilities of the corresponding version. Note that some will still stay in 3.6.x version at least for now.

Comment: Thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1) If gnome 3 team releases the new version for 12.04 officially, we wont have to add the remaining two ppas and the latest version will be available in the first repository itself.

?) Will a 13.04 user get any additional features by adding the second repository along with the first?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and run these commands;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gdm gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool
```

You will be asked to configure the display manager and
you must choose gdm.  You don't need to unistall any others.

Once you restart, you will see the gdm login screen,
and there you can choose gnome instead of unity.
This also means that you can leave Unity installed in
case you want to switch back to it.

You may find that Gnome 3.8 is very roughly done so
you will need to find tweaks to fix it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know Canonical add its own adjustment to fit with the many Ubuntu versions they release and to streamline transition between upgrades.

1. Currently After running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
   ```

Reboot.

`uname -a` returned:

```
"Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-32-generic #47~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 16:22:28 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux"
```

---

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After this you will have Gnome 3.8 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Gnome 3.8 != kernel 3.8
This comment is very, very misleading.